# Adding a non-jar file to the Java class path

Tags: java, classpath

I'm trying to make a .txt file available to my application via the class path.  In my startup script--which is co-located in the same folder as the .txt file--I've set the following:

set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%CD%\sample.txt
java -classpath %CD%\sample.txt

In my application, I've tried the following:

1. getClass().getResource("sample.txt")
2. getClass().getResource("/sample.txt")
3. getClass().getResource("classpath:sample.txt")

None of the above work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the `CLASSPATH` for things that don't contain classes?

Comment: @Daniel - It's fairly common to use the classpath for non-class resources (e.g. default property files, message bundles, templates).

Comment: Did you try `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassloader().getResource()`? The classloader used by `getClass` depends on the class you`re calling the method on.

Comment: Did you try using %CD%\ as a classpath instead of %CD%\sample.txt? If sample.txt is located in it, it should be found.

Comment: @Rob:  All those things are possible, but none are the answer to Daniel's question.  I'd like to hear why *Ignatius* is accessing resource that are not in a Jar file.  Not theories, specifics.

Comment: @Andrew - Sure, no problem asking for specifics. I just interpreted the comment broadly, i.e. "why would you ever do this?". I don't disagree that it would be nice to have the "why" for some context in this particular instance.

Comment: @Rob  I think we are on the same wavelength.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4):

You must pack you txt file inside jar or place it in directory included in classpath.

Comment: Wrong, of course you can add files to your classpath.
For example (in *nix):

java -cp "lib/*:etc"

In lib you have a bunch of jar files and in etc you have .txt, .xml, .properties, etc.

You then load them up with getResourceAsStream("myFile.txt")

Comment: "Wrong, of course you can add files to your classpath."

You've just repeated what this answers says - placing the files in a directory (`etc`), then adding that directory to the classpath (`java -cp etc`).

Answer (score 1):

You should add to your classpath the **directory** containing the file, and not the file itself:

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%CD%
```