# Trouble with parsing XML in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

So I was following [this tutorial](http://blog.sanaulla.info/2013/05/23/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java/) where I pretty much copy pasted the code from the SAX parser example. I created the same employees.xml file in the same folder as my java class. The error I get is `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null` on this line of code:

```
parser.parse(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("employees.xml"),handler);
```

You can view the rest of my code here if it's of any help: [pastie link](http://pastie.org/9649260)
Does anyone know how to make it read the xml file properly?  Or if there are any other suggestions on a good way to parse XML in java please share. Thanks

Comment: @Zhuinden who's talking of Android here? I guess your comment even adds more confusion than clarifying anything...

Comment: @GyroGearless Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ClassLoader, try using this :

InputStream is = SAXParserDemo.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("employee.xml");

source : http://www.coderanch.com/t/369908/java/java/ClassLoader-getSystemResourceAsStream

Thanks,
Dev

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the `ClassLoader` class for the `getSystemResourceAsStream` indicates that it returns a `null` when the resource can not be found.

So it is recommended to make sure, prior to calling `parser.parse`, to check that the result of `getSystemResourceAsStream` is not null.

The documentation also says

> Open for reading, a resource of the specified name from the search path used to load classes.

So it means that it is not necessarily searching the directory where the current class file is located, but rather the general system `CLASSPATH`.

If you are just using pure Java, you can open a plain `FileInputStream` without a class loader. If you are aiming for a bean or some other implementation that dictates a dependence between the location of your class and the location of the XML file, use the current class's class loader as indicated in Dev G's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class folder, in eclipse you can see [this](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm), in netbeans see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans), or without any IDE you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764620/adding-a-non-jar-file-to-the-java-class-path). Finally you want to try this:

> parser.parse (SAXParserDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("/employees.xml"), handler);

instead of:

> parser.parse(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("employees.xml"), handler);